# Is it possible to fit a linear model with only a response variable?

Tags: r, glm, lm

If I do this, I get two coefficients (intercept and year)

```
data <- data.frame(accidents=c(3,1,5,0,2,3,4), year=1:7)
glm(accidents ~ year, family=poisson(link = log), data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         year  
     0.7155       0.0557
```

But the correct answer is 0.944

```
data <-data.frame(accidents=c(3,1,5,0,2,3,4))
glm(accidents ~ ., family=poisson(link=log), data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  
  0.944
```

Is there a way to specify the glm formula for just the response variable? If I use the second formula with the first data frame I get the wrong answer because the "." also includes the "year". In the second data frame I'm cheating because there is only one column.

Comment: You might want to check the section on formulas in the Introduction to R too ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's the incantation that you are looking for:

```
glm(accidents ~ 1, family=poisson(link = log), data)
```

Using it with your original data frame:

```
data <- data.frame(accidents=c(3,1,5,0,2,3,4), year=1:7)
coef(glm(accidents ~ 1, family=poisson(link = log), data))
(Intercept) 
  0.9444616
```

Also, as Ben Bolker mentions, the R Introduction document that ships with R includes [a nicely  informative section on the grammar of the formula interface](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Formulae-for-statistical-models).